# Symfony create database

Tags: symfony

When I run symfony console doctrine:database:create, I get this error: Could not create database "app" for connection named default
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42P04]: Duplicate database: 7 ERROR:  database "app" already exists

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: The error is quite clear: "database "app" already exists". You've already created it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was using symfony console, I should have been using php bin/console. It worked.

Comment: you might want to investigate _why_ that worked. Probably it is because they each are using different database credentials. The symfony cli is integrated with Docker and will automatically use docker db creds with no config. bin/console uses the creds in the .env file. My guess is now you have two databases with different creds. If I recall - the docker creds will be used by the application. tho I am not certain about that part.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I definitely will investigate and learn more about why this happened